# High Number of commits through Ebean

Tags: java, oracle, ebean

I am working on an application with high number for DML operations due to which log file sync wait event is observed. We are using ebean framework for querying the Oracle database. I was looking for a way to reduce the number of commits. Is it advisable to use JDBC batch using batch size attribute for transactional calls.

Comment: Well, depends.  *Maybe* for some statements..... What version of Oracle?  What version of JDBC drivers?  Are you updating a few rows at a time?  Thousands?  How often are you committing?  Oracle generally does a good job; if you are seeing lots (but be careful to ensure "lots" is really meaningful), likely mismatch of JDBC drivers/Oracle version, using JDBC features instead of Oracle driver features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it advisable to use JDBC batch using batch size attribute for
> transactional calls.

Assuming a transaction is inserting, updating or deleting more that 1 bean/row then in short **yes**.

The caveat is that in terms of application code the actual execution of DML can occur later with statement flush at batch size, at commit time etc. This means statements can execute later in application code (like at commit time).

This typically only really matters to application code when application code is looking to handle exceptions like db constraint violations, missing foreign keys, unique constraints etc and actually continue the transaction. In this case we might need to add explicit `transaction.flush()` into the application code to ensure the statements have been executed and hit the database.